# Unity. Не воспроизводится анимация Partycle System из скрипта

Tags: unity3d

Я к `GameObject` добавил компонент `Particle System` и хочу его воспроизводить например при столкновении с другим объектом через скрипт.
Для этого я снял галочку с `Play On Awake` и написал такой код для воспроизведения анимации системы частиц:

```
GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Emit(8); 
GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().Play();
```

Но все равно нет анимации. Что делать ? В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте `prefab` ваших частиц (у меня в примере это smoke). И при столкновении объектов создавайте эти частицы в нужном вам месте:

```
GameObject smokePuff = Instantiate(smoke, gameObject.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
```

Edited:

После определенного времени или события можете просто уничтожить данный объект использовав: `Destroy(gameObject);`.

Comment: а потом этот геймобджект дизейблить? получается тогда пулл таких вот геймобджектов нужно создать?

Comment: @ВиталийБелоусов если вы про `smokePuff`, то они сами уничтожаются по истечению их времени жизни (то что вы задаете в редакторе).

Comment: как называется модуль и параметр который отвечает за уничтожение?

Comment: @ВиталийБелоусов извиняюсь, дал неверный комментарий. Частицы не уничтожаются, а просто пропадают. Для уничтожения можете использовать обычный `Destroy(gameObject);` после определенного времени или события.

Comment: спасибо! Вы мне очень помогли!